# Twig concatenation on variables

Tags: php, twig

I'm using twig.

I am trying to fetch values from my `answer` array in a dynamic way.

```
{% set value = question.slug %} // eg "satisfied_with_response"
{{ answer.satisfied_with_response }} // eg "4"
```

So I am trying to concatenate the response object;

```
{{ answer.value }} // doesn't work
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{ answer[value] }}` should work - but only if `answer` is an array.

Citing the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables):

> For convenience's sake `foo.bar` does the following things on the PHP
>   layer:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid property;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid method (even if `bar` is the constructor - use `__construct()` instead);
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `getBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `isBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, return a null value.
>
> `foo['bar']` on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, return a null value.

If you need to have the same features `foo.bar` provides you could use `{{ attribute(answer, value) }}`